# What does b' mean when reconstructing an autoencdoer?

Tags: autoencoder

Im just learning AutoEncoder, and I was reading from this website: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/dA.html 
and I didn't get what b' means.

So I tried to build autoencoder with tied weights.

For example,

Encoding : hid = s(x*w+b)

x : ( 1000, 2000 )

w : ( 2000, 500 )

b : ( 500, 1 )

-> hid : ( 1000 , 500 )

And when I decode encoded data,

decode : y=s(hid*w'+b')

w' : (500, 2000)

so hid*w' will be (1000,2000) 
and I have to add b', and its shape should be (2000,1) but I only have b with shape of ( 500, 1).

What have I done wrong here?

I found some code, and they just randomly made bais with shape of number of inputs, i.e., (2000,1) and optimized it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found my answer, and I post it for one's convenience. 
When decoding AE, you may want to make a bias vector which has a shape of (n_input). 
So in my example, I have to make a new bias vector b* : (2000,1) and use this b* to reconstruct inputs and optimize weights and b* together